# how to use SQLite with Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, sqlite

I want to show only a single row from my database in qt in a `tableview`.
This is my current code:

```
void Favorites::on_pushButton_load_fav_clicked()
{
MainWindow conn;
QSqlQueryModel *modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
conn.connOpen();
QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
qry->prepare("select username from Waehrung_MMI"); 
qry->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry);
ui->tableView_favs->setModel(modal);

 conn.connClose();
qDebug () << (modal->rowCount());
}
```

Now it shows the whole column but I only want to show for example row 17 of this column.

Comment: Why do you select all rows?

Comment: you need to know what is special about row 17 and build your query accordingly !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL's [limit](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) functionality in order to get a single row.

```cpp
   void Favorites::on_pushButton_load_fav_clicked() {
       MainWindow conn;
       QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
       conn.connOpen();
       QSqlQuery * qry = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
       qry->prepare("select username from Waehrung_MMI limit 1");
       qry->exec();
       modal->setQuery( * qry);
       ui->tableView_favs->setModel(modal);
       conn.connClose();
       qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @h-gomaa said, you need to write your query properly.

When you call `prepare`, it should be something like this, assuming you have an `id` in your table:

```
qry->prepare(QString("SELECT username FROM Waehrung_MMI WHERE id = :id"));
qry->bindValue(":id", 17);
```